# Fallo al realizar peticion POST en java con AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, post

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para android y esta realiza una petición POST enviando unos valores a un decodificador de televisión. La aplicación genera los valores correctamente pero a la hora de enviar los datos al aparato da varios errores entre los cuales son timeout, no route to host, y alguno parecido. Me he asegurado de que puedo acceder desde el navegador del teléfono a la ip y de escribir bien la url y aveces va y otras no.

Uso un script en python para crear un servidor y que me muestre la petición que realiza la aplicación para ver que no hay ningún error en los parámetros pero lo que si que he notado es que la petición tarda en realizarse. Es decir, la aplicación se conecta al servidor, manda la cabecera que contiene el host, el user-agent, y demás datos... pero no envía los parámetros hasta pasados unos segundos (10-15s) o hasta que cierro la aplicación.

He probado aumentando el connectionTimeout pero da igual el tiempo que le ponga, me da el mismo fallo. Parece que es de conexión pero les pasa a bastante gente que le he pasado la app para que la pruebe con su decodificador.A algunos les a ido bien, a otros les da problemas de conexión como el error de no route to host o conexion timeout, pero a uno se le a dañado el sistema y a tenido que reinstalar el firmware usando un cable rs232. En teoría solo estoy pasando los datos a una pagina del decodificador y no debería fallar hasta tal punto, pero si la petición se queda a medias si que podría quedarse pillado el servidor no?

Bueno os dejo el código que uso para realizar la petición POST y espero que podáis echarme una mano.

```
public PostTwo(String url, String params) throws IOException {
    try {
        URL url1 = new URL("http://"+url);

        HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
        client.setRequestMethod("POST");

        client.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        //client.setRequestProperty("arg1","valor");
        client.setDoOutput(true);
        client.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(params.getBytes().length);
        //client.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);


        OutputStream outputPost = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());


        outputPost.write(params.getBytes());
        outputPost.flush();
        outputPost.close();


        client.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Como llamas a este método? Directamente de un `Activity` o desde un `AsyncTask`?

Comment: has probado tu url con el mètodo post con hurl.it o postman??? Creo que eso te dara idea de que sucede. Tambièn es importante saber si se desplega algùn error.

Comment: Lo llamo desde un AsyncTask, en android no te deja hacer una conexion a la red sin llamarlo desde un asynctask. Probare lo de hurl.it pero la cosa es que funciona a veces y al mas minimo corte de señal o variacion ya no va, o hace la peticion a medias. No entiendo como conectandose al servidor tarda en enviar los parametros del formulario.  Porque en el servidor de python sale que se conecta (casi siempre a la primera) pero tarda en acabar la conexion y enviar los parametros. Forzando la aplicacion a cerrar se envian al  instante cuando la cierras.